Part ID Request, Diodes Package?
I'm trying to figure out what these 5 pin SMD guys labelled "DT"x on this Korg Minilogue synthesizer keyboard PCB are. Unfortunately though schematics are available for the synth itself, I cannot find one for the keyboard PCB. I would expect diodes here as they appear naively to be just keyboard matrix routing, but they have 5 pins and I don't know what "DT" would stand for. The only labelling is "600". Any help much appreciated.


Is the marking on the devices G9? From the resolution of the picture I can't be sure. The UMG9N suggested in the answer has a marking of G9 shown in the datasheet

My eyes aren't what they were...

Should be UMG9NTR, UMG9N SOT-353, SOT23-5.

So it's "Dual Transistor" then? Not what I was expecting!
